# Can I use the Mann-Whitney U test for this specific case?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a sample consisting of 750 Private Equity transactions where I got data on multiple variables such as return, size of investment, holding period and so on..

I am researching if two different groups (foreign and local investors) perform differently. I want to compare the two groups on some of these variables such as size (which is a continuous variable).

Can I use the Mann Whitney U test to test if there is a significant difference in the mean between the two groups? If I plot size of investment for both groups the distribution is similar..